# Cholera Vaccine: Dubai? Bangalore? Vancouver?

Tags: vaccinations

I am told that there is no Cholera vaccine to be had in the US for several more weeks.

I travel to BLR by way of DXB next week.

Is there a source in the airport in Dubai? Is it viable to imagine getting a dose in Bangalore upon arrival?

Living in Seattle, I could just about squeeze in a trip to Canada if that was a solution.

Comment: Assuming you're going on a business trip and you take reasonable precautions with food and drink, you are exceedingly unlikely to catch cholera in Bangalore.

Comment: Note that as long as you have access to a moderately well provisioned health care system, Cholera isn't particularly dangerous. The cure is [essentially salt water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholera#Treatment), and the only reason Cholera is still a problem in parts of the world is because parts of the world still don't have easy access to clean water.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The vaccine might not be immediately effective.

For example [Superdrug](https://healthclinics.superdrug.com/services/cholera-vaccination/) says

> You need to finish the course at least one week before travel. This means, that you need to get your first dose at least two weeks before travel.

In Vancouver? [Canadian Travel Clinics](https://www.canadiantravelclinics.ca/Vaccine-Information/Cholera) says

> Adults should have two doses of Dukoral and children will need three doses. These doses need to be spaced a week apart. You should aim to complete the entire course at least a week before you arrive at your destination.

Comment: This is a late comment, but for the benefit of others I'll still chime in. A travel clinic can also prescribe antibiotics, for you to take in case symptoms appear - I received both Dukoral and a just-in-case (i.e. fill it and bring it with you) prescription for azithromycin in advance of travel from my local travel clinic (located in Ontario). The idea is that the Dukoral *should* work, but if it doesn't and symptoms of cholera / ETEC-induced diarrhea appear, start the antibiotics.